# Excel- Inserting image from path using cell reference

Tags: excel, image, insert

I am using the below VBA to insert images from a local folder based on the  path in a cell.

The code is from this previous Question:
[Insert picture in excel macro which takes the file name as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020029/insert-picture-in-excel-macro-which-takes-the-file-name-as-reference)

```
' I set RowHeight in the excel to 125 and Picture Height to 100 so it fits nicely
' into the box that I want.
' That can be changed to suit your needs.
Sub InsertImageFullName()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Dim pic As String ' File path of a picture
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Rng = Range("A11:A16") ' Defining input range
    i = 1
    For Each cl In Rng

        pic = cl.Offset(0, 11)  ' Full path of the picture file:
                               ' Located in the same row, third column from A, i.e. column D
        If IsFile(pic) Then

            Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic) ' Inserting picture from address in D column
                                                             ' into column A

            With myPicture ' Setting picture properties
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue ' Keep aspect ratio
                .Height = 100 ' Set your own size
                .Top = Rows(cl.Row).Top
                .Left = Columns(cl.Column).Left
                .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            End With
            CenterMe ActiveSheet.Shapes(i), cl
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next    ' Looping to the Nth row, defined in:
            ' " Set Rng = Range("A13:A20") "

    Set myPicture = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub CenterMe(Shp As Shape, OverCells As Range)

    With OverCells
        Shp.Left = .Left + ((.Width - Shp.Width) / 2)
        Shp.Top = .Top + ((.Height - Shp.Height) / 2)
    End With
End Sub
Function IsFile(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if the provided name points to an existing file.
'Returns FALSE if not existing, or if it's a folder
    On Error Resume Next
    IsFile = ((GetAttr(fName) And vbDirectory) <> vbDirectory)
End Function
```

This works very well except for two issues that I am unable work out.

Firstly, I have assigned this to a CMD button which when clicked calls the macro, but here is the strange thing, it moves the CMD button to the first Cell where an image should be displayed (ie the first result).

For example:  I have a path in L11 which should display an image in A11 and then step down the sheet. What happens is it moves the command button and then steps to A12 with an image, A13 etc.  Odd!

The second issue, which I feel is related, is it moves the image results of say A11 to A12, then A12 to A13 etc. Despite the script stating no vertical offset...  The script is only currently running A11:16 and in A16 it places two images.  The one from above cell and the correct one.

So, the loop is working and pulling out the correct number of images, but due to the CMD button moving to where the first result is, seems to create a faux offset!

Any ideas? Use something instead of a CMD to call the macro?

Many thanks
A

Comment: In addition to this, I removed the command button and called the macro from Developer tab.  Instead of moving the now non-existant command button, it moved two images I had as 'header' images into cells A11 and A12 then continued the script from A13... The last two cells had duplicate images..